# Rspec not loading ControllerMacros module in Linux (but fine on OS X)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I have written some controller tests in a Rails app that uses Devise and Rspec. Following [this guide](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-%28and-RSpec%29), I've created a `controller_macros.rb` in the /spec/support/ directory. There is also a `devise.rb` file in the same directory, with:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
  config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller
end
```

Both files are being required in the `spec_helper.rb` file, with this line:

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }
```

**Now here is what is weird**: this approach works fine on an OS X laptop, but fails in my Linux desktop. They both use the same RVM settings, same gemsets, same everything.

The error I get when running the tests in Linux is:

```
uninitialized constant ControllerMacros (NameError)
```

Obviously the `controller_macros.rb` module is failing to load in Linux. I've seen SO answers suggesting that `config.extend` could be changed to `config.include`, but that doesn't fix the problem.

Any ideas where I can look or what I can test to help isolate the issue?

I'm using Rails 4.1.8 and Rspec 3.1.7.

Comment: Discovered that explicitly autoloading the path in application.rb with `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/spec/support)` fixes the problem - but I would love to know why one machine requires this and another does not.

Comment: getting this on Mac OS X with Rails 4.2 and Rspec 3.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding

```
require Rails.root.join("spec/support/macros/controller_macros.rb")
```

to the top of my spec/support/devise.rb file

Comment: Because the line     Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }    in spec/rails_helper.rb, spec/support/devise.rb is being loaded BEFORE spec/support/macros/controller_macros.rb . There are a number of ways to address this.

Comment: When I try that I get an additional rspec error: ```required /Users/.../spec/support/controller_macros.rb...
/Users/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require': no implicit conversion of Pathname into String (TypeError)```

Answer (score 4):

I struggled with this as well. Answers just weren't working for me. This is what I did (Ubuntu, Rails 4, Rspec 3):

`spec/rails_helper.rb`

```
# <snip> env stuff

require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'devise'
require 'support/controller_macros'

# <snip> some non-devise stuff

RSpec.configure do |config|

  # <snip> some more non-devise stuff

  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
  config.include ControllerMacros, type: :controller
end
```

`spec/support/controller_macros.rb`

```
module ControllerMacros
  def login_user
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    sign_in user
  end
end
```

`students_controller.rb`

```
require "rails_helper"

describe StudentsController, type: :controller do

  before do
    login_user
  end

  describe "GET index" do
    it "has a 200 status code" do
      get :index

      response.code.should eq("200")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks for this

Comment: The only solution that works for me. I've searched for this all around the web and the other ones don't seem to help